# Как исправить скрипт, чтобы ссылки были некликабельные?

Tags: jquery

Есть скрипт виджета

```
<script src="//lightwidget.com/widgets/lightwidget.js"></script>
<iframe src="//lightwidget.com/widgets/abcb041db5ef99681ad60f936d043.html" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" class="lightwidget-widget" style="width: 100%; border: 0; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

Как сделать, чтобы все ссылки были неликабельными?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1

```css
.lightwidget-widget{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//lightwidget.com/widgets/lightwidget.js"></script>
<iframe src="//lightwidget.com/widgets/abcb041db5ef99681ad60f936d043.html" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" class="lightwidget-widget" style="width: 100%; border: 0; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

Вариант 2

```css
.iframe-container{
    position: relative;    
}
.iframe-layer{
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="//lightwidget.com/widgets/lightwidget.js"></script>

<div class="iframe-container">
<iframe src="//lightwidget.com/widgets/abcb041db5ef99681ad60f936d043.html" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" class="lightwidget-widget" style="width: 100%; border: 0; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
<div class="iframe-layer"></div>
</div>
```